# row wise difference difference in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+ --------+----------+----------------+
| case_id | activity | end_time       |
+ --------+----------+----------------+
| 1       | A        | 1/1/2011 00:37 |
| 1       | B        | 1/1/2011 12:09 |
| 1       | C        | 1/3/2011 03:37 |
| 1       | D        | 1/3/2011 11:21 |
| 1       | E        | 1/3/2011 19:10 |
| 1       | F        | 1/4/2011 15:31 |
| 2       | G        | 1/1/2011 12:39 |
| 2       | A        | 1/1/2011 00:29 |
| 2       | B        | 1/1/2011 15:40 |
| 2       | C        | 1/4/2011 14:53 |
| 2       | D        | 1/4/2011 23:02 |
| 2       | E        | 1/5/2011 09:04 |
| 2       | F        | 1/6/2011 06:32 |
| 3       | H        | 1/2/2011 02:03 |
| 3       | A        | 1/1/2011 03:03 |
| 3       | B        | 1/2/2011 15:55 |
| 3       | C        | 1/5/2011 14:20 |
| 3       | D        | 1/5/2011 21:55 |
| 3       | E        | 1/6/2011 13:47 |
| 3       | F        | 1/7/2011 16:31 |
+ --------+----------+----------------+
```

Expected Result

```
+ --------+----------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
| case_id | activity | end_time       | diff in sec                          |
+ --------+----------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
| 1       | A        | 1/1/2011 00:37 | 41520(row 1 end_time-row 2 end_time) |
| 1       | B        | 1/1/2011 12:09 | 30720                                |
| 1       | C        | 1/3/2011 03:37 | 27840
+ --------+----------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, why are your results limited to three rows?  What happens to the rest of the rows?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: I am using sql-server ,                                                                           
case_id activity    end_time  diff in sec
1   A   1/1/2011 0:37         31000(row 1 end_time-row 2 end_time)
1   B   1/1/2011 12:09        32400(row 2 end_time -row 3 end_time)
1   C   1/3/2011 3:37           ....(row 3 end_time - row4 end_time)

Comment: This doesn't help us understand why there isn't a row for D, E, F G & H

Comment: How do you get 32000? Isn't it 12:09 - 00:37 = 11:32 = 11 hours and 32 minutes = 41520 seconds?

Comment: Not even an ounce of explanations... (oh man look at this sarcastic comment)

Comment: sorry guys the first row difference would be 41520 and second row 30720

Comment: @ShahaveAlam: You can edit your question any time to make corrections or add further information. Using comments for that is no good way.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for something like this

```
SELECT 
    case_id, 
    activity, 
    end_time, 
    DATEDIFF( SECOND, end_time, LEAD(end_time) OVER (ORDER BY case_id, activity))
FROM your_table
ORDER BY case_id, activity
```

but the [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2012) function is available only since SQL Server 2012. You haven't mentioned which version you use.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT 
    case_id, 
    activity, 
    end_time, 
    DATEDIFF( SECOND, end_time, NextRow)
FROM your_table as CurrentRow
outer apply (select top  1 end_time from your_table  as x where x.Identit_Field > CurrentRow.IdentityField) as NextRow
```